# UWP MediaPlayerElement keep Transport Controls from Overlapping video

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm building a universal windows media player app. Trying to get the Transport Controls from MediaPlayerElement to never overlap with the video it is playing. Currently the controls can overlap the media like this:

[How it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00C20.png)

I'd like for the player window to look something like this:

[How I would like it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1q3X.png)

I'd basically like to add margin to the bottom of the box that contains the video. Is there any way to address the box that contains the video without addressing the transport controls as well?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to make `Transport Controls`'s background transparent?

Comment: Hey! My initial goal is to insure the transport controls never overlap with the video which I have achieved thanks to help from here. But I have also also been trying to address the transport controls background with a custom style with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP MediaPlayerElement keep Transport Controls from Overlapping video

For the scenario, you could realize this feature by custom `MediaPlayerElement` style. Please check the following style I added two rows into the default style and place `TransportControlsPresenter` into second row.

```
<Style TargetType="MediaPlayerElement">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MediaPlayerElement">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="Transparent" />
                    <Image
                        x:Name="PosterImage"
                        Source="{TemplateBinding PosterSource}"
                        Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        />
                    <MediaPlayerPresenter
                        x:Name="MediaPlayerPresenter"
                        IsFullWindow="{TemplateBinding IsFullWindow}"
                        MediaPlayer="{TemplateBinding MediaPlayer}"
                        Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}"
                        />
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="TransportControlsPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding AreTransportControlsEnabled}"
                        />
                    <Grid x:Name="TimedTextSourcePresenter" />

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! I had been doing so by adding margin around the MediaPlayerPresenter but putting the ContentPresenter in it's own grid is much more efficient.